# How to display current Date and Time in textview inside of Fragment?

Tags: android, date, android-fragments, textview

I would like to display current Date and time in a Textview in my app fragments, in the Format : DD/MM/YEAR:H:Min but I have no idea how to code this up as I am new to programming. Where/What to begin with?

my current code :

```
package com.example.myshops;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater; 
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class Monday_fragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener { private TextView datetimetext;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item1_fragment, container, false);

    Button nextpageButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.Item2Button);
    nextpageButton.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) getActivity());
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.nextpageButton:



        break;
    }





    datetimetext.setText("" + DateFormat.format("dd/MM/yyyy kk:mm", System.currentTimeMillis()));





    //---Inflate the layout for this fragment---
//return inflater.inflate( R.layout.item1_fragment, container, false);



}



}
```

Comment: your switch did not include the setText, if you want it on every onClick, do it before you call switch

Comment: can u give a more specific explanation about it ? as im a beginner , have no idea about it .. @Boe-Dev

Comment: please check the changes in my code

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
yourTextView.setText("" + DateFormat.format("dd/MM/yyyy kk:mm", System.currentTimeMillis()));
```

it should work

try to change your code to this

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    datetimetext.setText("" + DateFormat.format("dd/MM/yyyy kk:mm", System.currentTimeMillis()));

    switch (v.getId()) {    
    case R.id.nextpageButton:
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: check my fixes, I had one error. 'kk' show you the 24 hours

Comment: where do i put the code ? inside the fragment ? where i do need to put this one on ?

Comment: it doesnt display the date and time at all @Boe-Dev

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm").format(System.currentTimeMillis() * 1000L);
```